# Do you have it in you to convey the following information in just one sentence like a native speaker? (Just imagine Lord Kitchener pointing at you)

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

I want to say that most questions on the test are asked from hardcore biology and there are few if any questions from chapters like  ' Where Does Our Food Come From' or ''Diseases'. I want to say all this in one sentence. Below is my attempt. Please critique.

> They ask questions mostly from hardcore biology and not so much from
> chapters like 'Where Does Our Food Come From' or 'Diseases'.

Comment: ask questions about or on biology.

Comment: @Michael Harvey  I meant Lord Kitchener. He was a famous British Field Marshal. I misspelt earlier. I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

---

They *mostly* ask**ed** questions *about/on* hardcore biology and not so much from chapters like 'Where Does Our Food Come From' or 'Diseases'.

---

Notes:

That is casual, spoken English. In a formal written context the following types of modifications might appear, although perhaps not precisely:

"not so much" -> "however, not extensively from", "mostly" -> "mainly", "like" -> "such as"